# linux checking if /dev/sdax and /dev/ttyxxx are for the same device

Tags: linux, posix

my usb device has a serial port and a mount point, so i've got a `/dev/sdax` and `/dev/ttyxxx` in my /dev folder, how can i find out if `/dev/sdax` and `/dev/ttyxxx` are for the same device in linux?

Comment: I don't think that is easy: a `/dev/ttyXXX` means a serial interface, and a `/dev/sdaX` means a block device. Look into `dmesg` output perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `/dev/disk/by-path` and `/dev/serial/by-path`, if you have those directories.  For instance I have:

```
/dev/disk/by-path:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 28 18:10 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.3-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 28 18:10 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.4-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan  7 10:54 pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  7 10:54 pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  7 10:54 pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  7 10:54 pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-0:0:0:0-part3 -> ../../sda3

/dev/serial/by-path:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 28 18:10 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 28 18:10 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.1-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 28 18:10 pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.2-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB2
```

The names matching `pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.*` all belong to the same physical device (in this case a 3G modem).